# settimeout while audio.duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to read an array of sentence asynchronously by audio; but i want to wait the duration of current audio before reading another sentence.
I'm trying to `settimeout` while audio duration, i `onloadmetadata` but it does not work. i think audio.duration work only in `onloadedmetadata`. when i debug i got the right duration in onloadedmetadata and `NaN` out of it
Here is what i have done.
Excuse my english

```
var j = 0, texte = "";
function listen(callback) {
  var sentence = texte[j];
  if (j < texte.length) {
    j++;
  } else {
    j = 0;
    texte = "";
    return;
  }
  callback(sentence, listen);
}



function play (sentence, callback) {
// Play the received speech
googleTTS(sentence, 'fr', 1)   // speed normal = 1 (default), slow = 0.24
.then(function (url) {
  console.log(url); // https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?...
  var audio = new Audio(url);

  var duration;
  audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
    duration = audio.duration;
  }

  audio.play();

  setTimeout(function(){
    callback(play);
  }, duration);

});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding and `ended` event handler to your `audio` object:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  callback(play);
});
audio.play();
```

This event will trigger when the current audio has finished playing.

Comment: I was just looking to see if there was an event that would trigger on completion. :)

Answer (score 0):

`audio.play()` probably doesn't pause to load metadata. That's why the callback is there. Therefore duration isn't being set before you're calling `setTimeout`.

Instead of

```
var duration;
audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
    duration = audio.duration;
}

audio.play();

setTimeout(function(){
    callback(play);
}, duration);
```

Try

```
var duration;
audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
    duration = audio.duration;
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(play);
    }, duration);
}

audio.play();
```

Comment: I think `audio.play();` should be also in `onloadedmetadata ` !